# WSO2 ESB FileConnector2.copy copy files to destination 200+ times

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

would somebody please kindly provide inside and guidance on how to address the following FileConnector.copy issue?  I am using wso2esb version 4.9 and FileConnector2.

I have a sequence that utilizes FileConnector2 COPY operation to copy file to a FTP location. The COPY operation copies a file to the destination multiple times even there is no concurrency issue that I am aware of! What interesting is that the number of times a file was copied is depending on the environment it is running on. On the dev environment, a file was copied 17 times. On the production, a file was copied 200+ times. I am trying to understand what drive this behavior. Did I mis-configure the FileConnector's COPY operation? I'd provided the sequence definition and network traffic below. Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Sequence definition that does the file copy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="SendFile2VendorSeq" onError="FileUploadFailSeq"
trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<property action="remove" name="ClientApiNonBlocking" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
<dblookup description="Get CDR files to be upload">
  <connection>
    <pool>
      <dsName>jdbc/DB_DS</dsName>
    </pool>
  </connection>
  <statement>
    <sql><![CDATA[
      SELECT QUERY HERE
    ]]></sql>
    <parameter expression="get-property('vendorCode')" type="VARCHAR"/>
    <result column="vendor_dest" name="vendorDest"/>
    <result column="file_name" name="fileName"/>
    <result column="vendor_id" name="vendorId"/>
    <result column="file_path" name="fileSource"/>
    <result column="vendor_code" name="vendorCode"/>
    <result column="id" name="fileId"/>
  </statement>
</dblookup>
<!-- CHECK TO SEE IF A ROW IS RETURNED. IF NOT THEN EXIT -->
<filter xpath="boolean(get-property('fileSource'))">
  <then>
    <property
      expression="fn:concat(get-property('fileSource'),get-property('fileName'))"
      name="sourceFile" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <fileconnector.isFileExist>
      <source>{$ctx:sourceFile}</source>
    </fileconnector.isFileExist>
    <switch source="//fileExist">
      <case regex="true">
        <log description="logEntry" level="full"/>
        <!-- Log the transaction in Database -->
        <log description="LogEntry" level="custom">
          <property
            expression="fn:concat('Uploading ', get-property('fileName'), ' (id:', get-property('fileId'), ') to vendor ', get-property('vendorCode'))" name="message"/>
        </log>
        <dblookup description="LogTX">
          <connection>
            <pool>
              <dsName>jdbc/DB_DS</dsName>
            </pool>
          </connection>
          <statement>
            <sql><![CDATA[SELECT record_TX(?,?)]]></sql>
            <parameter expression="get-property('fileId')" type="INTEGER"/>
            <parameter expression="get-property('vendorId')" type="INTEGER"/>
          </statement>
        </dblookup>
        <!-- Conduct file copy -->
        <fileconnector.copy>
          <source>{$ctx:fileSource}</source>
          <destination>{$ctx:vendorDest}</destination>
          <filePattern>{$ctx:fileName}</filePattern>
        </fileconnector.copy>
        <!-- Update the transaction with status -->
        <dblookup description="LogTX">
          <connection>
            <pool>
              <dsName>jdbc/DB_DS</dsName>
            </pool>
          </connection>
          <statement>
            <sql><![CDATA[SELECT record_TX(?,?,?,?)]]></sql>
            <parameter expression="get-property('fileId')" type="INTEGER"/>
            <parameter expression="get-property('vendorId')" type="INTEGER"/>
            <parameter type="CHAR" value="S"/>
            <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="Success"/>
          </statement>
        </dblookup>
        <log description="LogEntry" level="custom">
          <property
            expression="fn:concat('Successfully uploaded ', get-property('fileName'), ' (id:', get-property('fileId'), ') to vendor ', get-property('vendorCode'))" name="message"/>
        </log>
        <drop/>
      </case>
      <default>
        <log description="LogEntry" level="custom">
          <property
            expression="fn:concat(get-property('fileName'), ' (id:', get-property('fileId'), ') does not exists in the source directory.')" name="message"/>
        </log>
        <dblookup description="LogTX">
          <connection>
            <pool>
              <dsName>jdbc/DB_DS</dsName>
            </pool>
          </connection>
          <statement>
            <sql><![CDATA[SELECT record_TX(?,?,?,?)]]></sql>
            <parameter expression="get-property('fileId')" type="INTEGER"/>
            <parameter expression="get-property('vendorId')" type="INTEGER"/>
            <parameter type="CHAR" value="S"/>
            <parameter type="VARCHAR" value="File does not exists in the source directory."/>
          </statement>
        </dblookup>
      </default>
    </switch>
  </then>
  <else>
    <drop/>
  </else>
</filter>
</sequence>
```

A sample of network output shows the behavior.

```
Mon Jan 30 11:46:00 2017 [pid 21385] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:00 2017 [pid 21384] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:00 2017 [pid 21386] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 66.90Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 30 11:46:00 2017 [pid 21388] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:00 2017 [pid 21387] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:00 2017 [pid 21389] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 67.74Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 30 11:46:00 2017 [pid 21392] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:01 2017 [pid 21391] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:01 2017 [pid 21393] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 31.43Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 30 11:46:01 2017 [pid 21395] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:01 2017 [pid 21394] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:01 2017 [pid 21396] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 64.64Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 30 11:46:01 2017 [pid 21398] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:01 2017 [pid 21397] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:02 2017 [pid 21399] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 64.84Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 30 11:46:02 2017 [pid 21401] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:02 2017 [pid 21400] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:02 2017 [pid 21402] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 47.52Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 30 11:46:02 2017 [pid 21404] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:02 2017 [pid 21403] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:02 2017 [pid 21405] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 58.88Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 30 11:46:02 2017 [pid 21407] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:03 2017 [pid 21406] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:03 2017 [pid 21408] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 52.50Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 30 11:46:03 2017 [pid 21410] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:03 2017 [pid 21409] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:03 2017 [pid 21411] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 63.34Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 30 11:46:03 2017 [pid 21413] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:03 2017 [pid 21412] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:04 2017 [pid 21414] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 69.12Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 30 11:46:04 2017 [pid 21416] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:04 2017 [pid 21415] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:04 2017 [pid 21417] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 56.66Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 30 11:46:04 2017 [pid 21419] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:04 2017 [pid 21418] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:04 2017 [pid 21420] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 66.30Kbyte/sec
Mon Jan 30 11:46:04 2017 [pid 21422] CONNECT: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:04 2017 [pid 21421] [userName] OK LOGIN: Client "Some-IP-address"
Mon Jan 30 11:46:05 2017 [pid 21423] [userName] OK UPLOAD: Client "Some-IP-address", "/test/file.T70130IN03.csv", 1607 bytes, 68.93Kbyte/sec
```

Log entries from the system log file. it looks like the mediator takes more than 2 minutes to end its operation. Within this 2 minutes or so, it repeatedly copies the file to the destination over and over again until some sort of timeout, I guess.

```
[2017-02-02 15:24:58,250] DEBUG - ClassMediator Start : Class mediator
[2017-02-02 15:24:58,250] DEBUG - ClassMediator invoking : class org.wso2.carbon.connector.FileCopy.mediate()
[2017-02-02 15:25:46,851] DEBUG - ThreadingView Thread state summary for PassthroughHttpServerWorker threads - Blocked: 0.0%, Unblocked: 100.0%
[2017-02-02 15:25:46,881] DEBUG - ThreadingView Thread state summary for PassthroughHttpServerWorker threads - Blocked: 0.0%, Unblocked: 100.0%
[2017-02-02 15:26:46,855] DEBUG - ThreadingView Thread state summary for PassthroughHttpServerWorker threads - Blocked: 0.0%, Unblocked: 100.0%
[2017-02-02 15:26:46,884] DEBUG - ThreadingView Thread state summary for PassthroughHttpServerWorker threads - Blocked: 0.0%, Unblocked: 100.0%
[2017-02-02 15:27:29,479] DEBUG - ClassMediator End : Class mediator
[2017-02-02 15:27:29,479] DEBUG - SequenceMediator End : Sequence <CopyFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after decompile the FileCopy.class from FileConnector. Apparently, there's a FOR loop in the case when filePattern is specified in the configuration of the mediator. After I removed filePattern and specified the file in the source, it works as expected.

```
<sequence name="CopyFile" onError="AppDefaultFailSeq" trace="disable" 
xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
      <fileconnector.copy>
        <source>c://data/out/testFile.csv</source>
        <destination>ftp://userName:{password}@ftp.co.com/test</destination>
      </fileconnector.copy>
</sequence>
```